# Scala, convert list of dataframe into single dataframe then merge it with another dataframe with a specific column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of dataframe's I want to convert into single dataframe thereafter merge with another dataframe with a specific column of that dataframe and data type should be as it is of new dataframe.Where dfList is List[sql.Dataframe].Any help will be appreciated.

```
dfList[sql.Dataframe]=List([A: int]:Dataframe, [B: string]:Dataframe, [C: long]:Dataframe, [D: string]:Dataframe)

dfList = List( +-------+----------+--------+--------+
               |  A    |     B    |     C  |   D    |
               +-------+----------+--------+--------+
               |     41|    912AEQ| 2016022|      UJ|
               |     82|    912ARD| 2016022|      GH|
               |    903|    912AYQ| 2016022|      KL|
               |    454|    912AKK| 2016022|      KL|
               |     95|    912AHG| 2016022|      KH|
               +-------+----------+--------+--------+ )

the data type of df is Id: int, v1: string, v2: long, v3: string

df[Dataframe] =            
+---+---+-----------+-----+
| Id| v1|    v2     | v3  |
+---+---+-----------+-----+
| 11| AS| 0989765498|SDAWQ|
| 12| GH| 7654998599|TRUDR|
| 13| IO|10654998580|ABUCK|
| 14|1JG|65499855101|KLBCK|
| 15| RT|10265499852|BCKKL|
+---+---+-----------+-----+            

The newDF will be combination of dfList and df.
The datatype of newDF should be Id: int, A: int, B: string, C: long, D: string 


newDF =
    +---+------+----------+--------+--------+
    | Id| A    |     B    |     C  |   D    |
    +---+------+----------+--------+--------+
    | 11|    41|    912AEQ| 2016022|      UJ|
    | 12|    82|    912ARD| 2016022|      GH|
    | 13|   903|    912AYQ| 2016022|      KL|
    | 14|   454|    912AKK| 2016022|      KL|
    | 15|    95|    912AHG| 2016022|      KH|
    +---+------+----------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete solution, Since you do not have any key to join two dataframes, you need to add an index column on both, join them and drop index at last. Create a single dataframe from a list of dataframe by reducing and union.

```
import spark.implicits._

  //Create dfList dataframe

  val d1 = spark.sparkContext
    .parallelize(
      Seq(
        (41, "912AEQ", 2016022l, "UJ"),
        (82, "912ARD", 2016022l, "GH"),
        (903, "912AYQ", 2016022l, "KL")
      ))
    .toDF("A", "B", "C", "D")


  val d2 = spark.sparkContext
    .parallelize(
      Seq(
        (454, "912AKK", 2016022l, "KL"),
        (95, "912AHG", 2016022l, "KH")
      ))
    .toDF("A", "B", "C", "D")

  val allD = List(d1, d2)  //list of dataframe

  //create a singe dataframe from list of dataframe
  val dfList = allD.reduce(_ union _)


  //Create df dataframe
  val df = spark.sparkContext
    .parallelize(
      Seq(
        (11, "AS", 989765498l, "SDAWQ"),
        (12, "GH", 7654998599l, "TRUDR"),
        (13, "IO", 10654998580l, "ABUCK"),
        (14, "1JG", 65499855101l, "KLBCK"),
        (15, "RT", 10265499852l, "BCKKL")
      ))
    .toDF("id", "v1", "v2", "v3")

  val dfListWithIndex = addIndex(dfList) // and index column
  val dfWithIndex = addIndex(df).drop("v1", "v2", "v3") //add index column and remove unnecessary columns

  val newDF = dfWithIndex.join(dfListWithIndex, "index").drop("index") //join two dataframe and drop index column


  dfListWithIndex.show()
  dfWithIndex.show()
  newDF.printSchema()
  newDF.show

  def addIndex(df: DataFrame) = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    // Add index column
    df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
      case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
    },
    // Create schema for index column
    StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false))
  )
```

Comment: I have updated the answer for list of dataframe, please check it.

Comment: Shankar thanks,dfList is a list of dataframe's, please see the updated post.

Comment: was this helpful ?